# nice and SEO friendly url zend framework php

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

What's the best approach to generate nice URLs using Zend Framework?

Without Zend Framework and with MVC pattern I'd just use .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then parse the request parameters in PHP.

I'm now using Zend Framework and trying with zend_route in my bootstrap, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797619/zend-framework-how-to-rewrite-url-to-seo-friendly-url) and documented on [Zend website](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html).

My task is to convert a request:
 `example.com/pets-new-york` into `example.com/index/search/?q=pets%20new%20york` (current)

I can't make it work, how do I manage non existing files (-f) and dirs (-d) like it works in the first .htaccess example? More generally, what's the best approach to create nice URLs with Zend Framework with non-existing directories?

Comment: Usually with the ZF you don't "convert" a path, but a route parse the parameters and map the request to a specific controller and action.

Comment: Thanks! So what am I suppose to use then?

Comment: You posted the link yourself. You can start this simple example: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.usage The path template `user/:username` (`:username`) gets mapped against the request and if the route matches, the configured controller-action gets called, where you can retrieve the value of `:username` via `$this->getRequest()->getParam('username')`. For more complex examples, see below on the same page.

Comment: ouch! I was using the static router, that's why it did not work! In this case I have the bit "pets-new-york" in the variable I retrieve. 
Is there any way to parse a variable before getting into the controller? I was thinking to set the request with the parsed param  "pets new york".

Comment: As mentioned: Have look at the other examples ;) Should be possible (somehow) with the regex-router. Don't know, if I would complicate it. A simple `$slugParts = explode('-', $this->getRequest()->getParam('slug'));` within the controller seems trivial :)

Comment: ok, I'll see how to manage this, thanks!

Comment: Look At my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8968926/949273

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this. The following code will be create SEO Friendly url

Note: You have to be make sure that rewrite apache module should enabled on your server

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Let me know if you need any help.